# WCF Restful Https para um único método

Tags: c#, .net, mobile, restful, wcf

Tenho um WCF RESTful que estou utilizando para um aplicativo mobile, preciso que um único método, o de pagamento, utilize HTTPS, não quero habilitar HTTPS para o serviço inteiro porque alguns métodos retornam uma quantidade grande de dados e ficaria muito pesado para um celular.
Isso é possível? como?

Gostaria de saber se tem alguma propriedade ou outra forma de permitir que este método seja acessado apenas quando utilizar uma conexão segura... 
Algo do tipo...

```
[OperationContract]
[ExigirHTTPS(true)]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/Disponibilidade", RequestFormat =     WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
DisponibilidadeRS Disponibilidade(DisponibilidadeRQ request);
```

Comment: Para evitar que sua pergunta seja sinalizada, sugiro que você especifique um pouco melhor o que quer.

Answer (score 1):

O IIS pelo menos deixe os dois protocolos (http, https) ser habilitados ao mesmo tempo. Se tiveres accesso ao servidor, uma posibilidade, embora nao muito elegante, é usar regras de 'url rewrite' [(http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) que intercepte o url especifico e dirige ao https. Entao, os clientes podem usar http a vontade pelo resto do site.